# Call Web service with UrlString

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection

Im trying to call a web service with a UrlString but not sure how to call it? I know where i need to place the part of code but not sure how to code it. My coding from my .m file is below. If anyone could shed some light on it or have an example to work from would be a lot of help (read through quite a few webpages and now getting to the breaking point!)

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize characterimage;
@synthesize characterpicker;
@synthesize characters = _characters;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Load up NSArray
    _characters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"bergerac" , @"biarritz" , @"chareleroi" , @"liege" , @"oostende" , nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerView Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _characters.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_characters objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //Create UIImage
    UIImage *bergeracimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bergerac.JPG"];
    UIImage *biarritizimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Biarritz-Anglet-Bayonne_Airport_view_from_landing_strip.jpg"];
    UIImage *chareleroiimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Aéroport_de_Charleroi,_B737_Ryanair_-_2011.JPG"];
    UIImage *liegeimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Liege_airport.jpg"];
    UIImage *oostendeimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Luchthavengebouw_Antwerpen-Deurne.jpg"];

    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            characterimage.image = bergeracimage;
            self.urlString = @"http://www.google.com";
            break;
        case 1:
            characterimage.image = biarritizimage;
            break;
        case 2:
            characterimage.image = chareleroiimage;
            break;
        case 3:
            characterimage.image = liegeimage;
            break;
        case 4:
            characterimage.image = oostendeimage;
            break;
        default:
            characterimage.image = oostendeimage;
        break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttontapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //call your web service with self.urlString

}

@end
```

Comment: Sorry .m file!... Its been a long night

Comment: You should read up on the [URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA). As is, I think this question is probably too broad, but you'll find the answers you need there.

Comment: Ok looking into URL Loading System has confused me more would it be best to used a NSURLRequest within the IBAction?

Comment: You cannot possibly have read that document in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot call a web service using a simple url string. You need to use some of the apis provided by Apple to call web services.

You can go through this example : http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

This post explains how to use NSURLConnection for making synchronous and asynchronous requests.

Also , you can go through NSURLConnection class reference. There are some examples given by apple.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html